# Google App Engine Cloud SQL connection issue

Tags: google-app-engine, zend-framework2, google-cloud-sql

When trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL I get following error:

```
Connection error

Unable to find the socket transport "unix" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

I have been trying to solve this issue now for multiple hours, still nothing.

My config is as follows (in ZF2 config local.php):

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Mysqli',
        'host' => '',
        'database' => 'ar_captab',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'driver_options'  => [
            'unix_socket' => ':/cloudsql/some-app-v1-test:some-db'
        ]
    ),
);
```

I also added my application ID of my Google App Engine application to Access Control list (Authorized App Engine Applications) in Cloud SQL.

When I try to run this:

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');

$adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['db']);
$sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($adapter);

$select = $sql->select();
$select->from('example');
$select->where('1');

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results = $statement->execute();
```

I get the unix socket error. What I am missing?

Comment: Also the weirdest thing is that when I trying to access Google Cloud SQL from my local dev environment with remote account and IP it is working fine. But when trying to access it from the Google App Engine with same credentials, I get Unknown error 4294967295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I was because of the colon. You do not need it with Mysqli connection, only with PDO connection types.

So the correct config is:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Mysqli',
        'host' => '',
        'database' => 'some-database',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'driver_options'  => [
            'unix_socket' => '/cloudsql/some-app-v1-test:some-db'
        ]
    ),
);
```